# Galois group command for Magma online calculator?

Tags: galois-theory, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I need to test if a family of 7th deg and 13 deg equations are solvable. I'm new to *Magma*, so my apologies, but what would I type in,

http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

to determine the Galois group of $x^5+5x-12=0$ (for example)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> > P< x >:=PolynomialAlgebra(Rationals());
>
> > f:=x^5+5*x-12;
>
> > G:=GaloisGroup(f);
>
> > print G;
>
> Symmetric group G acting on a set of cardinality 5
> Order = 120 = 2^3 * 3 * 5

Although the permutation group on [1..Degree($f$)] is permutationally isomorphic to the Galois group, the bijection with the set of roots of your separable irreducible polynomial $f$ is not determined. For more details see the Magma handbook.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format your post.

Comment: Someone also recommended this [Magma site](http://www.math.wayne.edu/answers/magma2.10/htmlhelp/text701.htm). The reason is I found a [family of solvable equations](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155087/) of deg $p=5,7,13$. I already knew how to solve them in radicals, but I also wanted to explicitly determine their Galois group.

Comment: @Glasby Is there a way of making the base field finite, i.e. calculating the Galois Group of a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_7$?

Comment: Your code gives «User error: Identifier 'x' has not been declared or assigned» on Magma site (link to the site is given in OP). Should be `P<x>:=…`.

Comment: @Mathmo No GaloisGroup works for number field and orders, but finite fields are easy. The Galois group over a finite field of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ is a cyclic group of order $n$.

Answer (score 1):

GaloisGroup(FldFin, FldFin) is available. Make an extension of F_7 using your polynomial then call GaloisGroup.

GaloisGroup is also available for polynomials over char p function fields. Coerce your polynomial to be over a function field over F_7 and compute the GaloisGroup of that polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

For `x^10 - 1280/512*x^8 + 1120/512*x^6 - 400/512*x^4 + 50/512*x^2 - 
  1/512`, the web page can return the generator of Galois group:

```
R < x > := PolynomialRing (RationalField ());
f := x^10 - 1280/512*x^8 + 1120/512*x^6 - 400/512*x^4 + 50/512*x^2 - 
  1/512;
G := GaloisGroup (f);
G;
IsSolvable (G);
```