# How to construct $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta)$ with MAGMA?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, magma-cas

I'd like to ask the following question concerning a MAGMA command I'm probably not aware of.

> Is it possible to construct a field of the form $F=\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta)$ with MAGMA, where $\zeta$ denotes a primitive $m$-th root of unity in an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ with the property that gcd$(p,m)>1$?

I'm particularly interested in the case where $p=2$.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If $\zeta$ has irreducible degree $k$ over $\mathbb F_p$, then you are asking for the finite field $\mathbb F_{p^k}$.

Comment: What did the people who write and maintain the software say?  Surely you didn't skip asking the group of people who know the software best?

Comment: And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793914/29335) might be useful? Isn't it just a quotient ring? Surely it isn't hard to do quotients in MAGMA.

Comment: Thank you very mch for the three comments. Thanks for the linked reference. I missed the command SplittingField. Unfortunately, I didn't ask the people developing MAGMA before. So, one could do $Kx<x>:=PolynomialRing(GF(p));$, then $f:=x^m-1;$ and then $L:=SplittingField(f);$. @rschwieb you can post this and / or your linked reference as an answer, if you like.

Comment: Please edit: this is ok with [magma-cas] but is not a [magma] question, maybe [fields] if you wanna use 5 tags which is good :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have changed the tags.