# How Do I Calculate The Galois Group And Intermediate Fields Of A Certain Extension Using Magma?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions, magma-cas

here [MAGMA Commands for Galois Theory calculations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793914/magma-commands-for-galois-theory-calculations) it is discussed how to calculate the galois group when the the field that is fixed is say the rationals. But what if the field that is fixed is $\Bbb{F}_2(x)$ the polynomial ring with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_2$.

To be specific i look at the normal closure of extension $\Bbb{F}_2(x) \subset \Bbb{F}_2(x,y,w)$ where $y$ and $w$ satisfy equations:

$$
y^2 + y = x^3 + x,\qquad
(x^7 + x + 1)(w^2 + w) = (x^5 + x) y + x^2 + x
$$

This extension of the normal closure is finite and galois but how does one obtain the galois group + the intermediate fields as i tried using commands Subfields() and GaloisGroup() but these only work i believe if the ground field is the rationals or some number field. Thoughts?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Both $\Bbb{F}_2(x,y)/\Bbb{F}_2(x)$ and $\Bbb{F}_2(x,y,w)/\Bbb{F}_2(x,y)$ are Artin-Schreier extensions (hence cyclic Galois of degree two). But I don't see why $\Bbb{F}_2(x,y,w)/\Bbb{F}_2(x)$ should be Galois? The intermediate field has the non-trivial automorphism $y\mapsto y+1$, but I don't see if that extends to the bigger field.

Comment: What *normal closure* exactly are you referring to?

Comment: F2(x)⊂F2(x,y,w)