# Solve $x^5+3x^3+x+\frac{1}{x^2}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve this equation $$x^5+3x^3+x+\frac{1}{x^2}=0.$$
It's possible to notice that if we write $3x^3$ as $2x^3+x^3$, then
$$
x^3\left(x^2+2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+x^3+\frac{1}{x^2}=0,
$$
which equals
$$
x^3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+x^3+\frac{1}{x^2}=0.
$$
But I have no idea how to continue further.

Comment: If [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%5E5+%2B+3*x%5E3+%2B+x+%2B1%2Fx%5E2+%3D+0) does not find a closed-form solution then there probably is none, and you have to solve it numerically.

Comment: @MartinR You made it to 100k. Well done!

Comment: multiply through by $x^2.$  Now you have a polynomial of degree 7.  This polynomial has no rational roots.  You should not expect a polynomial of degree 5 or greater to be solvable.

Comment: @MartinR Without determine Galois group, still I think we can not reach to the healthy conclusion .

Comment: The polynomial of seventh order has 1 real root and 6 complex roots.
$$1+x^{3}+3x^{5}+x^{7}\simeq\left(x+ 0.711579764439192\right) \left(x+ 0.274401076934264+ 0.903369883711077 \,\mathrm{i}\right) \left(x+ 0.274401076934264- 0.903369883711077 \,\mathrm{i}\right) \left(x- 0.0319403820294392+ 1.62172369651801 \,\mathrm{i}\right) \left(x- 0.0319403820294392- 1.62172369651801 \,\mathrm{i}\right) \left(x- 0.598250577124421+ 0.491251338921359 \,\mathrm{i}\right) \left(x- 0.598250577124421- 0.491251338921359 \,\mathrm{i}\right)=0$$

Comment: @gpmath, thx, btw, have you got this by wolfram or others solvers?

Comment: @MartinR R, yes, it seems like lack of rational roots but how to prove it neatly?

Comment: @lonestudent Unfortunately, the Galois group has size $7! = 5040$ so the roots have no algebraic relations with each other , apart from pairs of complex roots being conjugates of each other. That, along with the absence of rational roots, tells us that the present roots are best computed numerically.

Comment: Maple with command: factor(x^7 + 3*x^5 + x^3 + 1, complex);

Comment: Glad to see you again @SarveshRavichandranIyer ! Sometimes I've seen types of higher degree polynomials that can be solved by radicals but that WolframAlpha failed to solve.  Do you know any input for Wolfram that can directly determine the Galois group? Or is there an input that directly determines whether the algebraic solution exists or not?  If there is, it would be really great to know.

Comment: @Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer, cool! May, you, please, describe briefly, how have you count this Galois group?

Comment: @lonestudent I use [Magma Calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) and [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642329) to find the Galois group. To find algebraic relations is more trickier : there's no "route" but I try to type variations of the equation into [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/) and see if others have done anything other than calculus. If not, then I give up (after, of course, trying the rational root theorem, maybe seeing if some obvious substitution might work, etc.).

Comment: @LeonBrick Kind of difficult in one comment, but there's a branch of mathematics called Galois theory. The "Galois group" of a polynomial is roughly a "measure" of how much the roots "algebraically" depend upon each other. For example, is one of the roots a square of another root? Maybe it's the reciprocal. Maybe it's one more than the other root. And so on. If the Galois group's size is small compared to the factorial of the degree of the polynomial, then typically such polynomials should be easy to factorize. In this case, that's not true. I'll use another comment to elaborate.

Comment: For example, take the polynomial $x^6+x^4+x^2+27$. In this case, the polynomial might be difficult to factorize, but if $\alpha$ is a root, so is $-\alpha$. So you expect that the substitution $x^2 = y$ will work. It turns out the Galois group size is $48$ which is smaller than $6! = 720$, so the polynomial will become of degree $3$ (after which, it turns out, the roots will all stop depending algebraically on each other). I mentioned in a comment above how the Galois group can be used to detect if expressions factorize or not, and if roots could have algebraic relations with one another.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer In general I always appreciate that you leave comments that are *understandable* to non-experts too .

Comment: @lonestudent Thank you, running on your support and belief that I can deliver.

Comment: @LeonBrick The lack of *rational* roots is easy to prove with the rational root theorem. The lack of *radical* roots is much more difficult to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *rational equation*:

$$
x^5 + 3\,x^3 + x + \frac{1}{x^2} = 0
$$

shares the same solutions of the *polynomial equation*:

$$
\underbrace{x^7 + 3\,x^5 + x^3 + 1}_{p(x)} = 0\,.
$$

So, once the *seven first-attempt solutions* on the unit circle have been calculated:

$$
x_k = \cos(2\,k\,\pi/7) + \text{i}\,\sin(2\,k\,\pi/7)
\quad \quad \text{with} \; k = 1,2,\dots,7
$$

it's sufficient to update them about ten times by applying the *Aberth-Ehrlich method*:

$$
x_k' = x_k - \left(\frac{p'(x_k)}{p(x_k)} - \begin{aligned}\sum_{j=1;\,j\ne k}^7\end{aligned}\frac{1}{x_k-x_j}\right)^{-1}
$$

i.e

```
p[u_] := u^7 + 3 u^5 + u^3 + 1
d = Exponent[# /. u -> v RandomReal[], v] &[p[u]];
x = N@Table[Cos[2 k π/d] + I Sin[2 k π/d], {k, d}];
Do[x[[k]] = x[[k]] - (p'[x[[k]]]/p[x[[k]]] - 
   Sum[If[j == k, 0, 1/(x[[k]] - x[[j]])], {j, d}])^(-1), {n, 8}, {k, d}]
```

from which:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& x_1 = 0.598251 + 0.491251\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_2 = -0.274401 + 0.90337\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_3 = -0.71158 - 7.35225\cdot 10^{-19}\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_4 = 0.0319404 - 1.62172\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_5 = -0.274401 - 0.90337\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_6 = 0.598251 - 0.491251\,\text{i}\,; \\
& x_7 = 0.0319404 + 1.62172\,\text{i}\,. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Of course this doesn't prove whether or not it's possible to express them by radicals.

Comment: Presumably $x_3$ is the real root of $p$.

Answer (score 2):

*Totally useless but funny (at least to me)*

For the only real root, write
$$f(x)=x^7+3 x^5+x^3+1$$ as $$f(x)=-4+25 (x+1)-54 (x+1)^2+66 (x+1)^3-50 (x+1)^4+$$ $$24 (x+1)^5-7(x+1)^6+(x+1)^7$$

Now, consider the above as a series expansion to  $O\left((x+1)^{p+1}\right)$ with $p\geq 7$ and use power series reversion to get
$$x=-1+\sum_{n=0}^p a_n\,(f(x)+4)^n+O((f(x)+4)^{p+1}$$  Since we want $f(x)=0$ then
$$x_{(p)}=-1+\sum_{n=0}^p a_n\,4^n$$

Using $p=8$ which is exactly the polynomial, you should get, as an estimate
$$x_{(8)}=-\frac{1075280545512027477}{1490116119384765625}=-0.721609$$

Now, repeat and you will get (exact fraction reprted as decimal numbers)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & x_{(p)} \\
 7 & -0.721609 \\
 8 & -0.718758 \\
 9 & -0.716772 \\
 20 & -0.711791 \\
 30 & -0.711595 \\
 40 & -0.711581 \\
 50 & -0.711580 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit** *(for more fun !)*

Transform the series to their equivalent $[1,n]$ Padé approximants  $P_n$, that is to say
$$P_n=\frac {-4+ a_{(n)}\,(x+1) } {1+\sum_{p=1}^n b_p\,(x+1)^p }\quad \implies x_{(n)}=-1+\frac 4{a_{(n)}}$$ which is the same as using the first itterate of a Newton-like method of order $(n+2)$.

This will generate  the converging sequence
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  -\frac{21}{25} ,
  -\frac{309}{409},
  -\frac{4245}{5881},
  -\frac{58357}{81881} ,
  -\frac{807253}{1134777} ,
  -\frac{3730663}{5243699},
  -\frac{155226133}{218150521},
  -\frac{2152852853}{3025454937}
\end{array}
\right)$$

The last one in the list is $$x_{(7)}=  -\frac{2152852853}{3025454937}={\large{\color{red}{-0.711579}}}88$$

Comment: @TeM. If you knew who was my master, my guru, who is still my God (capital on purpose), you would not be very surprized. Be sure that I appreciate. Cheers :-)

Comment: @TeM. Just for the fun, assuming that you have 30 seconds to waste, have a look at my edit.

Comment: Just wondering is \frac{2152852853}{3025454937}=0.71157988 irrational number since the Rational Root Theorem does not consider it as a rational solution? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance. This is not the solution (which is irrational. For example $$-\frac{71766252868840089984679014456794928069798468947749}{100854
   825355243616352598809693657706050583163486975}$$ igives $100$ exact figures but it is not the solution

Comment: Thanks you for the immediate reply. This is big! I thought it would be the solution to the degree 7 polynomial (at least from the chart) - Why is it not a solution?

Comment: @NoChance. Because it can not be rational. Very often in answers, speaking about the solution, I use to write $\color{red}{\text{the "exact" solution}}$. The double quotes make a big difference

Comment: Got it - Thank you very much. This is good education.